# Peer-review flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

What do you think is the best approach to reproduce this flowchart in Tikz? Personnaly i would reproduce it using the Matcha.io drawing tool however i would like to know your thoughts about this choice?

[image]

Thanks for your feedback and advices

Comment: Look at the [tutorial for diagram on the pgf manual](https://tikz.dev/tutorial-chains)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: I just asked for the best way to approach the problem. Someone else hopefully was able to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the right libraries and a few helpful keys and styles, this can be done with plain TikZ.

The `cd`'s `shift left` and `shift right` key only works good with the `graphs` library when the start and target anchors are fixed but for the other cases, the combination of `nudge right` and the `to path`s from the `ext.paths.ortho` library of my `tikz-ext` package are enough.

For node placement, the `chains` library is used.

Since in the left column all nodes are left-aligned, the `west below` placement strategy (provided by `ext.positioning-plus`) is enough.

For the middle column, I'll define placement keys `mwb` (middle west below) and `meb` which places the new node either left-aligned with `middle-begin`, the first node in the `middle` chain, or right-aligned.

For `middle-6` (“Send it to a friend …”) this won't work anymore but we can use `nudge right` again.

This key uses the value of `/tikz/diff text width` which is also used by `box level` to decrease the width of a node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta, cd, chains,
  ext.positioning-plus,
  ext.paths.ortho,
  graphs, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >={Straight Barb[scale=2, angle'=45, round]},
  box/.style={
    shape=rectangle, align=flush center,
    fill=blue!50, draw, rounded corners},
  base text width/.initial=.5\linewidth,
  diff text width/.initial=10mm,
  box level/.style={
    text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/base text width}
           -#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diff text width}},
  every on chain/.style=box,
  %%%
  graphs/shift left/.style={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/shift left={
      .5*(#1)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diff text width}}},
  graphs/shift left/.default=1,
  graphs/shift right/.style={/tikz/graphs/shift left={-(#1)}},
  graphs/shift right/.default=1,
  nudge right/.style={xshift=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diff text width}},
  nudge right/.default=1,
]
\begin{scope}[start chain=left going west below]
  \node[on chain, box level = 0] {
    \textbf{Step 1: Design Your Project}\\
    Are you an expert on all of the topics you will be studying/methods
    you will be using, and do you have time to do the project by yourself?};
  \node[on chain, box level = 1] {
    Contact other scientist and ask them to collaborate.};
  \node[on chain, box level = 0] {
    Are you/your coauthors confident that you know
    how to design your experiment and statistics properly?};
  \node[on chain, box level = 1] {Contact a statistican for advice.};
  \node[on chain, box level = 0] {\bfseries Step 2: Conduct Your Research};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[
  start chain=middle going mwb,
  mwb/.style args={of #1}{west below=of (middle-begin)(#1)},
  meb/.style args={of #1}{east below=of (middle-begin)(#1)},
]
  \node[on chain, box level = 0, north right=of left-begin] {
    \textbf{Step 4: Write Your Paper}\\ Have your coauthors read it?};
  \node[on chain, box level = 2] {
    Send it to your coauthors.};
  \node[on chain = going meb, box level = 1] {
    Did your coauthors approve the paper in its present form?};
  \node[on chain, box level = 2] {
    Make the suggested revisions.};
  \node[on chain = going meb, box level = 2] {
    Are you confident that your paper is ready for publication?};
  \node[on chain, nudge right, box level = 3] {
    Send it to a friend/fellow scientist. Did they approve it?};
  \node[on chain = going meb, box level = 1] {
    \bfseries Step 5: Submit Your Paper to a Suitable Journal.};
\end{scope}
\graph[
  use existing nodes, /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts,
  edge quotes={auto=false, fill=white, inner sep=+.2em},
  east down/.style={left anchor=south east, right anchor=north east},
  west up/.style  ={left anchor=north west, right anchor=south west},
  west down/.style={left anchor=south west, right anchor=north west},
  No/.style={*|, "No"}, Yes/.style={east down, shift right, "Yes"},
  /tikz/c/.style={shape=coordinate, name={#1}},
]{
  (left-1)   ->[No]                            (left-2)
             ->[|*]                            (left-3),
  (left-1)   ->[Yes]                           (left-3)
             ->[No]                            (left-4)
             ->[|*]                            (left-5),
  (left-3)   ->[Yes]                           (left-5)
             ->[-|-]                           (middle-1)
             ->[No]                            (middle-2)
             ->[|*]                            (middle-3),
  (middle-1) ->[east down, shift right, "Yes"] (middle-3)
             ->[No]                            (middle-4)
             ->[west up, shift right]          (middle-2),
  (middle-3) ->[Yes]                           (middle-5),
  (middle-5) ->[west down, nudge right=.5, |*, "No"] (middle-6)
             ->[west up,   nudge right=.5, |*, "No"] (middle-4),
  (middle-5) ->[Yes, near start, "" c=m57] (middle-7),
  (middle-6) ->["Yes", -*] m57,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: There are alternatives to TikZ-CD's `shift left`, even as part of `ext.paths.ortho`. One could also add special anchors to each node that correspond to the appropriate point on the rectangle's sides. This might actually be easier on the input syntax once it's properly set up.